# What Does the Wrench do?

Tags: die2nite

I've just started playing [Die2Nite](http://www.die2nite.com/) and I came across an "*adjustable spanner*".  When I mouse over it, the item info is such:

> With an adjustable spanner, you can choose between building something and breaking something  Something might not necessarily be an object...

...so I assume the info is hinting at **[Weaponry](http://die2nite.wikia.com/wiki/Items#Armory)**

I put it in the bank, then removed it again to see what class of item it is, and it turns out that it is indeed listed in the *armoury* section.

---

What exactly does the wrench do?  If I can use it as a weapon, can I also use it to "*build something*", as stated in the info?  Are there *stats* of any kind for the weaponry of the game that can give me a better understanding of the items *(i.e. damage, etc?)* ?

<strike>Also, can I play tennis with it?</strike>

Comment: In general, the effectiveness of a weapon can be discussed in terms of 'has X% chance to kill Y zombies on use. Has Z% chance to break."

For example, a Fat Cat is, if I recall correctly, 100% chance to kill 1 Zombie, 20% chance to 'break'.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the most important question in your last paragraph. Namely, "Can I play tennis with the wrench?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a late answer, but i used the adjustable spanner to open a food crate. so it can be used to open certain heavy objects.

i also used it to help 2 zombies to the next life.

Answer (score 6):

According to the French wiki ([translated version](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twinpedia.com%2Fhordes)) as a weapon the wrench has a 1 in 3 chance of killing a zombie and a 20% chance of breaking.